# Disable Scrolling on Body Without Hiding The Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I would like to disable scrolling on the HTML body  without hiding the scroll bar  . I have tried the following options:

- `height: 100vh;` `overflow: hidden;`
- `position: fixed;`

Both disabled the scrolling but hid the scroll bar.

Comment: What is the usecase here?

Comment: On mac's default preferences you're not going to see a scrollbar anyway until you start scrolling. The question therefore sounds quite browser + system specific.

Comment: Check out the [document scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event). You could have JS resetting the scroll to 0 every time the user scrolls, maybe?

Comment: @NicolasGoosen That sounds like a horrible idea and is almost guaranteed to a) be a performance hit to the site, and b) create a very jerky user experience.

Comment: @connexo the whole of OP's question sounds like a horrible idea. :P

Comment: No, it does not. @mplungjan The standard scenario for this is blocking interaction with the page's elements via an overlay, and in this scenario you don't want the underlying page to scroll anymore. Hiding the scrollbar creates a jumpy layout because it essentially adds like 20px to `100vw`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you solve this:

```css
html { 
  height: 100vh; 
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: calc(100vh + 0.3px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Find a value large enough to still create an overflow, but small enough to not actually result in scrolling.

Comment: (... and remove the `overflow: hidden`, otherwise it'll still not show a scrollbar.)

Comment: @CBroe Sure it will.

Comment: How will `overflow: hidden` _ever_ show a scrollbar? I can't see how this is supposed to work.

Comment: _"in which case you'll always have a scrollbar"_ - if the parent element is the scrollable one, yes. But that would have to explicitly get `overflow: auto` or `scroll` then, with the default `visible` it won't work.

Comment: @CBroe Just [checked](https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/XWzZpQG), seems you are right. Will edit this into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable scrollbar but you can add `padding-right`. For example:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
```